# Pivoting Row Counts into Ratios Column? (in MS-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've got the following query:

```sql
select a.IsCancelled, count(*) from tblTask a
    inner join tblTicket t on a.TicketID = t.TID
    group by a.IsCancelled
```

Which gives me something like:

```text
IsCancelled      Count
0                7851
1                11235
```

Say I wanted to add another column with the percentages relative to each row, I should get the following:

```text
IsCancelled      Count     Ratio
0                7851      0.41135
1                11235     0.58865
```

This is called a Pivot correct? How would I accomplish this calculation? What do I add to my query above to make this happen? Thanks ;)

### IMPLEMENTATION

I ended up modifying diaho's answer a bit as follows:

```sql
declare @tbl table (IsCancelled bit, [Count] int)
insert into @tbl
    select a.IsCancelled, count(*) [Count] from tblTask a
        inner join tblTicket t on a.TicketID = t.TID
        group by a.IsCancelled
select IsCancelled, [Count], round(cast([Count] as float)/(select sum([Count])
    from @tbl),5) [Ratio] from @tbl
```

Comment: No that's not a pivot. What dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
DECLARE @Total INT

SELECT @Total = select count(1) from tblTask

select a.IsCancelled, count(1), count(1)/@Total
from tblTask a
inner join tblTicket t on a.TicketID = t.TID
group by a.IsCancelled
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a subquery.  The query below should work in sqlserver and mysql, but I'm not sure it will work in ever rdbms.

```
select a.IsCancelled, count(*), count(*)/(select count(*) from tblTask) 
from tblTask a
inner join tblTicket t on a.TicketID = t.TID
group by a.IsCancelled
```

An alternate way...

```
select a.IsCancelled, count(*), count(*)/totalcount
from tblTask a,
tblTicket t,
(select IsCancelled, count(*) as totalcount from tblTask) as tablecount, 
where a.TicketID = t.TID
group by a.IsCancelled
```

The key here is to do this in one query or transaction or your count could change from one query to the next.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, nor any variation of it that I could think of. :(

Comment: Added an alternate/uglier way.

Comment: I don't think you can run a `SELECT` as one of the columns to return as you have in your first variation. Also for the second one, you would need to remove `IsCancelled` from the subquery, and join `tablecount` with `tblTask` somehow to access `totalcount`

Comment: I've just tested both of them in mysql and they do work.  i did try a simplified example without the other join.

Comment: ah, I was assuming sql-server/mssql

Comment: I've done the first query in mssql 2000 before.  made one more change to the 2nd query that might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
SELECT
  a.IsCancelled,
  Count = COUNT(*),
  Ratio = COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM tblTask a
  INNER JOIN tblTicket t ON a.TicketID = t.TID
GROUP BY a.IsCancelled
```

References:

- [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)
- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)